# nginx + fastcgi gives me wrong uri

Tags: nginx

i'm really start to configure nginx with config here:

```
   location / {  
      root html;
        fastcgi_param URI $uri;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        include /usr/local/nginx/conf/fastcgi_params;
    }
```

But when i go request to localhost/blablabla, i didn't see correct URI in fastcgi parameters:

```
Printing description of request->parameters:
{
    "CONTENT_LENGTH" = "";
    "CONTENT_TYPE" = "";
    "DOCUMENT_ROOT" = "/usr/local/nginx/html";
    "DOCUMENT_URI" = "/devicemanagement/status";
    "GATEWAY_INTERFACE" = "CGI/1.1";
    "HTTP_ACCEPT" = "*/*";
    "HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING" = "gzip, deflate";
    "HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE" = ru;
    "HTTP_CONNECTION" = "keep-alive";
    "HTTP_HOST" = "127.0.0.1";
    "HTTP_USER_AGENT" = "devicemgrd/845.4 CFNetwork/673.0.2 Darwin/13.0.0 (x86_64) (MacBookPro8%2C2)";
    "QUERY_STRING" = auto;
    "REDIRECT_STATUS" = 200;
    "REMOTE_ADDR" = "127.0.0.1";
    "REMOTE_PORT" = 53224;
    "REQUEST_METHOD" = GET;
    "REQUEST_URI" = "/devicemanagement/status?auto";
    "SCRIPT_NAME" = "/devicemanagement/status";
    "SERVER_ADDR" = "127.0.0.1";
    "SERVER_NAME" = localhost;
    "SERVER_PORT" = 80;
    "SERVER_PROTOCOL" = "HTTP/1.1";
    "SERVER_SOFTWARE" = "nginx/1.5.5";
}
```

A "/devicemanagement/status" is not what i type in browser.
Any ideas?